# Excel VBA Textbox_Exit Event Handler

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, exit, eventhandler

At a road block here.  Simple user form using three text boxes, one for user id, two to enter serial number using hand scanner.  User loads excel file, userform.show loads, user enters id then simple validation to verify numberic number, then focus set on first textbox, user scans barcode to input serial number, again simple validation to ensure numeric and length, same with last textbox, scan serial number, validate first textbox entry matches second textbox entry.

Hand scanner is used to input serial number and also returns a "return carriage" character; e.g. enter button press after serial number scan.

Using "return carriage" to fire textbox_exit event handler.  Issue is very intermittent but consistent.  I load userform, input data, when record is complete, data is transferred to object worksheet.  However, when troubleshooting, I initially open workbook and userform, create a few records, save, and close.  Everything works well and data is recorded and archived.  Issue generally arises when i load workbook a second time, enter data for one record, save, and begin second record.  Once serial number is entered into first textbox, exit event never fires using "return carriage".  I can manually transfer focus to other objects; e.g. diff textbox, but the overall operation is not as expected.

I have tried inserting application.eventhandler=true commands, different event handlers, as well as numerous code changes; e.g. exit sub at end of IF statements, to make this work.

Thought I would reach out to the community for some feedback.  FYI, issues still arises if I simulate hand scanner using copy/paste and enter key.

Example of exit event handler for first serial textbox below.

```
Private Sub SerialIn_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Cancel = False

If Not IsNumeric(SerialIn.Value) Then        'validate serial number is numeric

    'error msg serial number is not numeric
    Msg = "Opps, something went wrong!  Serial number was incorrect." _
        & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Rescan module serial number."
        MsgBox Msg, vbCritical, "Warning"           'display msg

    Cancel = True                               'stop user from changing focus

    SerialIn.SelStart = 0                       'highlight user text
    SerialIn.SelLength = Len(SerialIn.Value)    'select user text
    'Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(StopLightRed)  'display red stop light
    Exit Sub
Else
    If Not Len(SerialIn.Value) = 19 Then           'validate serial number length
        'error msg incorrect length
        Msg = "Opps, something went wrong!  Serial number was incorrect." _
            & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Rescan module serial number."
            MsgBox Msg, vbCritical, "Warning"

        Cancel = True                               'stop user from changing focus

        SerialIn.SelStart = 0                       'highlight user text
        SerialIn.SelLength = Len(SerialIn.Value)    'select user text
        'Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(StopLightRed)  'display red stop light
        Exit Sub
    Else
        SerialInTime.Caption = Now                      'record date and time
        'Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(StopLightYellow)   'display yellow WIP stop light
        Me.SerialOut.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

End If
End Sub

New code:

```
Private Sub SerialIn_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Cancel = ValidateSerialIn(SerialIn)
End Sub

Function ValidateSerialIn(ByVal TextBox As Object) As Boolean

If Not IsNumeric(SerialIn.Value) Then        'validate serial number is numeric
'error msg serial number is not numeric
Msg = "Opps, something went wrong!  Serial number was incorrect." _
    & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Rescan module serial number."
    msgbox Msg, vbCritical, "Warning"           'display msg

SerialIn.SetFocus
SerialIn.SelStart = 0                       'highlight user text
SerialIn.SelLength = Len(SerialIn.Value)    'select user text
'Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(StopLightRed)  'display red stop light

ValidateSerialIn = True

Else
    If Not Len(SerialIn.Value) = 19 Then           'validate serial number length
'error msg incorrect length
Msg = "Opps, something went wrong!  Serial number was incorrect." _
    & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Rescan module serial number."
msgbox Msg, vbCritical, "Warning"

'Cancel = True                               'stop user from changing focus

SerialIn.SelStart = 0                       'highlight user text
SerialIn.SelLength = Len(SerialIn.Value)    'select user text
'Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(StopLightRed)  'display red stop light

ValidateSerialIn = True
Else
    SerialInTime.Caption = Now                      'record date and time
    'Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(StopLightYellow)   'display yellow WIP stop light

    ValidateSerialIn = False
    End If
End If
End Function
```

Third go using Tim's TextBox_Change solution:

```
Private Sub SerialIn_Change()
Dim v
v = ScannedValue1(SerialIn.Text)

If Len(v) > 0 Then
    If Not IsNumeric(v) Then        'validate serial number is numeric
        'error msg serial number is not numeric
        Msg = "Opps, something went wrong!  Serial number was incorrect." _
            & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Rescan module serial number."
        msgbox Msg, vbCritical, "Warning"           'display msg

        SerialIn.Text = vbNullString
    Else
        If Not Len(v) = 19 Then           'validate serial number length
            'error msg incorrect length
            Msg = "Opps, something went wrong!  Serial number was incorrect." _
                & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Rescan module serial number."
            msgbox Msg, vbCritical, "Warning"

            SerialIn.Text = vbNullString
            'Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(StopLightRed)  'display red stop light
        Else
            SerialInTime.Caption = Now                      'record date and time
            'Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(StopLightYellow)   'display yellow WIP stop light
            SerialOut.SetFocus
        End If
    End If
End If
End Sub

'check if a value ends with vbcrlf or vblf
' - if yes strip that off and return the rest
' - otherwise returns empty string
Function ScannedValue1(vIn) As String
Dim rv As String
If Right(vIn, 2) = vbCrLf Then
    ScannedValue1 = Replace(vIn, vbCrLf, "")
ElseIf Right(vIn, 1) = vbLf Then
    ScannedValue1 = Replace(vIn, vbLf, "")
End If
End Function
```

Comment: If you want to detect the "Enter" then use the `Change` event to check if the textbox value ends with vbCrLf or vbLf (in that order): if it does, then trigger the "scan" action.  Note you need to set your textbox to "multiline=true" in order to capture the enter key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to detect the "Enter" from the scanner then use the `Change` event to check if the textbox value ends with `vbCrLf` or `vbLf` (in that order): if it does, then trigger the "scan" action.

Note you need to set your textbox to "multiline=true" and "EnterKeyBehaviour = true" in order for the Change event to capture the enter key.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

    Dim v

    v = ScannedValue(TextBox1.Text)

    If Len(v) > 0 Then
        TriggerScanAction v
        TextBox1.Value = ""
    End If

End Sub

'check if a value ends with vbcrlf or vblf
' - if yes strip that off and return the rest
' - otherwise returns empty string
Function ScannedValue(vIn) As String
    Dim rv As String
    If Right(vIn, 2) = vbCrLf Then
        ScannedValue = Replace(vIn, vbCrLf, "")
    ElseIf Right(vIn, 1) = vbLf Then
        ScannedValue = Replace(vIn, vbLf, "")
    End If
End Function

'execute some action triggered by a scanned value
Sub TriggerScanAction(v)
    MsgBox "You scanned " & v
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Tim for the advice, well try your solution and provide feedback.

Comment: Haven't had a chance to code a solution yet using this method, but doesn't Change event fire after a single character has been entered into textbox control?  Unsure how this would work given im scanning a serial number that contains 19 numerical characters, plus carriage return.

Comment: If you want to find out when a CR is entered you need to check on every change otherwise how would you detect it ?

Comment: So your saying on after each character is entered, check for CR?  Once CR has been identified, process data, else continue entering more characters, e.g. serial number characters?

Comment: Hi Tim, finally found some time to code a solution based on your feedback.  It appears to work.  Also tested on Win10 with Excel2016 and functions as expected. One additional question, I added by data validation criteria directly in change event.  Is this a bad habit? I attempted to perform data validation in  a subroutine, however, was unable to achieve the desired result.  If it is indeed good programming practice, I will continue my efforts

Comment: Typically you want to avoid doing too much in your event handler - if you need to apply business rules then splitting that out also lets you call the code from other places, so that's something to consider.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback will work to perform validations in separate subroutine.  I'm just checking if numeric and string length.  Shouldn't be too difficult.  Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

The `Exit` event has more to it than meets the eye. On most forms, one enters a value in a textbox and then clicks "OK", a command button. Tbx.Exit event occurs. It also occurs if you click anywhere else, such as a button to close the form. In your system the CR triggers the event as well, and that would appear to be the problem.

When a CR or TAB is entered in your Tbx  the form's tapping sequence takes over. The exit occurs, followed by the enter event of the next control in your tapping order. (Compare that to the manual change of focus that occurs when the user determines the next control.)

So, the solution should be not to use the Exit event but to let the CR initiate a change of focus, using the tapping order setting, which lands the focus on an "OK" button, then let that button's Enter event trigger its Click event (if it doesn't do that by default).

You probably want a cycle there, where the CR triggers the worksheet entry and the focus comes back to the Tbx. That's one more reason not to use the Exit event because you don't want an entry made in the worksheet when you exit the Tbx to close the form.

However, perhaps your form doesn't have or need an "OK" button. In that case I would recommend the `BeforeUpdate` event of the Tbx. Both `Exit` and `BeforeUpdate` occur in close succession. The sequence isn't important however (though that's not the reason why I forgot it :-)) but their nature. Use the exit event in the context of form control, setting focus or reacting to focus change. `BeforeUpdate` obviously refers to data. Each of these events is fine tuned to its own task and therefore does it better than the other.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation Variatus.  Given your feedback, I have modified my Exit handler to simply determine whether to give or keep focus using cancel command.  In order to decide if cancel is true of false, I am passing textbox contents to a function to evaluate user input, based on that evaluation, the function will return true or false back to Exit handler.

Comment: Will try solution tomorrow using Win2010 and Excel2016 with hand scanner.  Original code worked as developed on Win7 and Excel2016 and functioned as expected.  New solution functions as expected using Win7 and Excel2016.

Comment: Same result when using new code identified above, code hangs when executing textbox Exit handler.  Doesnt seem to be an issue using Win7 and Excel2016. Next steps will be use of Beforeupdate, tho im still unclear how this would work, particularly for last textbox in form.